# How can I get a file's modification date in DDMMYY format in Perl?

Tags: perl, file, datetime, date

What's the best way to get a file's modification date in DDMMYY format in Perl?

<sub>(Originally the question was "How to do it without the DateTime module". I removed this restriction in order to make the question more general.)</sub>

Comment: I found the answer I wanted, and removed the "no DateTime module" restriction, in order to make the question more generic.

Comment: ...which changes the question.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If this is the only date formatting I need to do and don't need any date features for anything else, I just use POSIX (which comes with Perl):

```
use POSIX;

my $file = "/etc/passwd";

my $date = POSIX::strftime( 
             "%d%m%y", 
             localtime( 
                 ( stat $file )[9]
                 )
             );
```

Forget about `-M` if you aren't using relative time. Go directly to `stat` to get the epoch time.

Comment: Stat() doesn't seem to work on Activestate Perl 5.24 on Windows Server 2012. How would I get a file date for a file on Windows Server?

Comment: Look through the Win32:: modules for those that know about the Windows filesystems.

Comment: Thanks. I've already did a search on DuckDuckGo, the Activestate community forum, and looked at CPAN at Win32::File. Some of the modules have not been updated in 10 years. But I have not found what I needed yet.

Answer (score 12):

See [Time::Piece](http://perldoc.perl.org/5.10.1/Time/Piece.html) for object oriented syntax. It also comes with Perl by default in versions 5.10 and next.
Usually at some later point you need more functionality. Using Time::Piece does not import anything beside `localtime` and `gmtime`. And you can ask it not to import anything too by just saying `use Time::Piece ();`.

```
use Time::Piece;
localtime((stat $filename)[9])->ymd;                # 2000-02-29
localtime((stat $filename)[9])->ymd('');                 # 20000229
localtime((stat $filename)[9])->dmy("");#is what you wanted



$perl -MTime::Piece -e 'print localtime(time)->dmy("")'
```

Comment: And it's core in 5.10, which is maybe relevant (since modules may be an issue here).

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATE**:  Note that this answer was to the original question, which specifically excluded use of DateTime modules.

To get modified time

```
my $mtime = (stat $filename)[9];
```

This returns the last modify time in seconds since the epoch.

Then, to translate to date components, use localtime -

```
my($sec,$min,$hour,$mday,$mon,$year,$wday,$yday,$isdst) = localtime($mtime);
```

Note that localtime returns 0 for Jan, 1 for Feb, etc, and $year is the number of years since 1900, so 109 -> 2009.

Then to output in the format DDMMYY -

```
print substr('0'.$mday,-2), substr('0'.($mon+1),-2), substr($year+1900,-2);
```

So it's easier - and less error-prone - to simply use Date::Format if you can.

Comment: POSIX::strftime('%m%d%y', $mtime) is also easier and less error prone

Answer (score 4):

Here's a reasonably straightforward method using POSIX (which is a core module) and `localtime` to avoid twiddling with the details of what `stat` returns (see [Edg's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1839877/how-to-get-files-modification-date-in-ddmmyy-format-in-perl/1839897#1839897) for why that's a pain):

```
use POSIX qw/strftime/;

my @records;

opendir my $dh, '.' or die "Can't open current directory for reading: $!";

while (my $item = readdir $dh) {
    next unless -f $item && $item !~ m/^\./;
    push @records, [$item, (stat $item)[9]];
}

for my $record (@records) {
    print "File: $record->[0]\n";
    print "Mtime: " . strftime("%d%m%Y", localtime $record->[1]), "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
use Date::Format;
print time2str("%d%m%y", (stat $filename)[9]);
```

Comment: Isn't supported or isn't installed?