# Perl - sort the log files from a directory, pick up the latest generated log file and print only specific data

Tags: perl

I am new to perl, I need to develop a script to sort the logs in a directory, pickup the latest file and copy only specific contants from the log file and print it to the new file. i have written a below perl script i need your valuable inputs.

```
my($dir) = "C:\Luntbuild_Logs\LACOPBOC LACOPBOC_LASQABOCFC_";
$file = #Here i want to pick up the last generated log file from the above dir
my($newLog) = "new.log";
while (<MYFILE>) {
    print "$line" if $line =~ /> @/;
    print "$line" if $line =~ /ORA-/;
 }
 close (MYFILE);

I want my code to pick up the last generated log file from the dir and print the specific lines and redirect the output to the new log file.
```

can you please correct me on the below code now my srript is able to sort and print the latest file (all files in the dir are txt files) but i am unable to perfom the action

```
use File::stat;
$dirname = 'C:/Luntbuild_Logs';
$timediff=0;
opendir DIR, "$dirname";
while (defined ($file = readdir(DIR)))
{
                if($file ne "." && $file ne "..")
                {
                                $diff = time()-stat("$dirname/$file")->mtime;
                                if($timediff == 0)
                       {
                                $timediff=$diff;
                                $newest=$file;
                       }
                if($diff<$timediff)
                                       {
                                $timediff=$diff;
                                $newest=$file;
                       }
        }
}
open(FILE,"<$newest");
my(@fprint) = <FILE>;
close FILE;
open(FOUT,">list1.txt") || die("Cannot Open File");
foreach $line (@fprint) {
    print "$line" if $line =~ /> @/;
    print "$line" if $line =~ /ORA-/;
    print FOUT $line;
}
close FOUT;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I find the newest created file in a directory?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/328673/how-can-i-find-the-newest-created-file-in-a-directory)

Comment: @tripleee, this question combines several different tasks, however.  That is only one of them.

Comment: Don't post multiple questions in one, either.

Comment: ALWAYS `use strict;` and `use warnings;` at the begining of your scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple way to get the files in a directory (note forward slashes work in Windows and are preferred):

```
chdir "C:/Luntbuild_Logs/LACOPBOC LACOPBOC_LASQABOCFC_";
my @files = <*>;
```

You should probably verify that you are only getting the correct type of file.  On Windows you can generally do this by the extension.  Suppose all of your files end with .log. Replace the last line above with:

```
my @files = grep {/\.log$/} <*>;
```

For the next step, I suggest you look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1839877/how-can-i-get-files-modification-date-in-ddmmyy-format-in-perl), which provides a number of solutions for finding the time a file was modified.