# Perl Script to read newest log file

Tags: perl

I'm trying to assemble a script that will first identify the newest log file created under a folder, then open it and look for specific data.  Basically, I will be looking in this log file for a specific error and print the errors into the new log file.

I understand how to perform sort in order to have the most recent file, but having trouble in reading the latest file and copying it to the new log file

```
use File::stat;

$dirname  = 'C:/Luntbuild_Logs';
$timediff = 0;

opendir DIR, "$dirname";

while ( defined( $file = readdir(DIR) ) ) {
    if ( $file ne "." && $file ne ".." ) {
        $diff = time() - stat("$dirname/$file")->mtime;
        if ( $timediff == 0 ) {
            $timediff = $diff;
            $newest   = $file;
        }
        if ( $diff < $timediff ) {
            $timediff = $diff;
            $newest   = $file;
        }
    }
}

print $newest;

$file1 = "$dirname/$file";

open( FILE1, "<$newest" );
my (@fprint) = <FILE1>;
close FILE1;

open( FOUT, ">list1.txt" ) || die("Cannot Open File");

foreach $line (@fprint) {
    print "$line" if $line =~ /> @/;
    print "$line" if $line =~ /ORA-/;
    print FOUT $line;
}

close FOUT;
```

Comment: What goes wrong? Why do you not use `or die` for both the opens?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Perl - sort the log files from a directory, pick up the latest generated log file and print only specific data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12050020/perl-sort-the-log-files-from-a-directory-pick-up-the-latest-generated-log-fil)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The primary problem is that you build the full file path in `$file1` but then open `$newest` which contains only the file name.

You really should improve your code by

- *Always* using `use strict` and `use warnings` at the start of your program, and declaring all variables with `my` at their point of definition
- Use lexical file and directory handles and the three-parameter form of open. Always test the status of an open and put `$!` in the `die` string so that you know *why* it failed
- Never put double-quotes around a variable unless you know what it does and that is what you want

Here is a refactoring of your code which follows these guidelines and also uses the built-in `-M` operator that returns the age of a file in days

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $dirname = 'C:/Luntbuild_Logs';
my ($newest_age, $newest_file);

opendir my $dh, $dirname or die $!;

while ( readdir($dh) ) {
  my $file = "$dirname/$_";
  next unless -f $file;
  my $age = -M $file;
  unless (defined $newest_age and $newest_age <= $age) {
    $newest_age = $age;
    $newest_file = $file;
  }
}

print $newest_file, "\n";

open my $out,'>', 'list1.txt' or die "Cannot open file: $!";

open my $in, '<', $newest_file or die $!;
while (<$in>) {
  print if /> \@/ or /ORA-/;
  print { $out } $_;
}

close $out or die $!;
close $in or die $!;
```

Comment: `$file1` actually does not contain the correct file name: It contains the last file name from the readdir.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your error might lie here:

```
open(FILE1,"<$newest");
```

You try to open the file with no path included (`readdir` only returns file name), which may or may not work, depending on what your current working directory is.

Since you do not check the return value of the `open` statement, you don't know if it failed or not. Most likely, you need to do something like:

```
open FILE1, "<", "$dirname/$newest" or die $!;
```

Always check the return value of all `open`, and `opendir` calls, because they can fail silently. And be sure to include:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

In your script, and correct the errors and warnings. It is your safest precaution against hard to detect bugs.

Comment: Another problem is that you use "0" as the special value for "`$timediff` has not been set yet". Imagine that your `readdir` returns three file names: one file modified an hour ago, one file modified this very moment and one file modified 10 minutes ago. In that case it will set `$timediff` to 0 again upon seeing the second file and therefore think that the third file is actually the newest -- even though it wasn't. Or imagine file timestamps that are in the future (yes, such stuff happens in general).

Comment: Correct, it would be more prudent to leave `$timediff` undefined, and check for definedness. However, not the main problem with this code, I think. Unless there are a great many files, it would perhaps be a good idea to do `($newest, @others) = sort { -M $a <=> -M $b } readdir(DIR)`